# How to add a button inside of 1 cell inside a table on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, cell

I'm trying to add a button that links out to another website inside of a cell in **SharePoint** but it keeps moving the button to either above or below the table and not inside of the cell.

Is it possible to do this with either an embed code or an HTML code that I could place within "**Edit Source**" under "**Content Editor**"?

Any help on this would be appreciated. I have been researching solutions all day.

The below is currently what is being used. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<span style="font-size: 10px;"> 
    <font face="Verdana">
        <a href="/sites/Global_OE/SitePages/Forms/ByAuthor.aspx"> 
            <strong> 
                <input name="HONDA" type="button" value="Case for Change &amp; Sponsorship                   " style="background-color: #336699; color: #ffffff;"/>
            </strong>
        </a>
    </font>
</span>
<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="ms-rteTable-default">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-default">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 206px;">​<br/>​<br/></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default" style="width: 20%; text-align: center;">
            <style="background-color: style="font-family: optima;">​<img src="/sites/Global_OE/homepagedraft/SiteAssets/SitePages/Test/Picture1.png" alt="Picture1.png" style="margin: 5px; width: 25px; height: 25px;"/><span class="ms-rteFontSize-4">Diagn​​ose &amp; Scope</span>​<br/></style="background-color:></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 20%;">
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default" style="width: 20%;">
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 20%;">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableOddRow-default">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 206px;">
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">
            <p>
               <span style="font-family: optima;">•Align to the business strategy</span></p>
            <p>
               <span style="font-family: optima;">•Align&#160;on what success looks like with leader and/ or sponsor</span></p>
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-default">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 206px; text-align: center;">
            <div>​OE&#160;</div>
            <div> Getting Started &amp; Tracking Progress<br/></div>
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​​​​​​​​​​<br/></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableOddRow-default">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 206px; text-align: center;">​Change Management<sup>3 
               <br/></sup>(Complex Change)<br/></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​<br/></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-default">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 206px; text-align: center;">​Organization Design<br/></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableOddRow-default">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 206px;">
            <div style="text-align: center;">​Everyday Change </div>
            <div style="text-align: center;">(Team Effectiveness)<br/></div>
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-default">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 206px; text-align: center;">​​Process Enablement<br/></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Cannot see the button tag inside your code?

Comment: How do I place the button tag inside the code?

Comment: just place this code: <button>Text</button> inside the cell and a button should show up there, probably need to look up a quick HTML course on YouTube or something to get familiar with the tags...

Answer (score 0):

The following code for your reference.

```
<table cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="ms-rteTable-default">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-default">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 206px;">​
            <span style="font-size: 10px;"> 
                <font face="Verdana">
                    <a href="/sites/Global_OE/SitePages/Forms/ByAuthor.aspx"> 
                        <strong> 
                            <input name="HONDA" type="button" value="Case for Change &amp; Sponsorship" onclick="window.location.href='/sites/Global_OE/SitePages/Forms/ByAuthor.aspx'" style="background-color: #336699; color: #ffffff;"/>
                        </strong>
                    </a>
                </font>
            </span>
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default" style="width: 20%; text-align: center;">
            <style="background-color: style="font-family: optima;">​<img src="/sites/Global_OE/homepagedraft/SiteAssets/SitePages/Test/Picture1.png" alt="Picture1.png" style="margin: 5px; width: 25px; height: 25px;"/><span class="ms-rteFontSize-4">Diagn​​ose &amp; Scope</span>​<br/></style="background-color:></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 20%;">
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default" style="width: 20%;">
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 20%;">
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableOddRow-default">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 206px;">
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">
            <p>
               <span style="font-family: optima;">•Align to the business strategy</span></p>
            <p>
               <span style="font-family: optima;">•Align&#160;on what success looks like with leader and/ or sponsor</span></p>
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-default">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 206px; text-align: center;">
            <div>​OE&#160;</div>
            <div> Getting Started &amp; Tracking Progress<br/></div>
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​​​​​​​​​​<br/></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableOddRow-default">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 206px; text-align: center;">​Change Management<sup>3 
               <br/></sup>(Complex Change)<br/></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​<br/></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-default">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 206px; text-align: center;">​Organization Design<br/></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableOddRow-default">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 206px;">
            <div style="text-align: center;">​Everyday Change </div>
            <div style="text-align: center;">(Team Effectiveness)<br/></div>
         </td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ms-rteTableEvenRow-default">
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default" style="width: 206px; text-align: center;">​​Process Enablement<br/></td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableOddCol-default">​</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTableEvenCol-default">​</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]